# Shortcut of special character suggestion in a popup in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any shortcut in Intellij Idea, if I type for example "**e**", a popup should appear and suggest me other special characters related to "e" letter like "**é, ê**"?

Android phones have this feature, if I type "e" and wait for a second, I see suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point having it on PC when you can very quickly switch keyboard language to have these symbols?

Comment: I really do not understand people who just downvote normal questions. To your question, people may have different needs, different habits like using Intellij instead of switching keyboard. I actually get used to use shortcuts of Intellij, it is practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Mac** if I hold down on keys that have similar but different representations in other regions of the world, I get that little popup menu from which I can choose a variant.

[image]

On **Windows** there is no equivalent to this.

But alternatively, I used the old way.

- Press **Windows + R**
- Write **charmap**
- Copy the character